# NSScrubber pan animation end notification

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit, caanimation, nstouchbar

The touchbar-specific `NSScrubber` control scrolls with inertia on a pan gesture.  I want to be notified of this animation's end to perform some function.

### Try 1

The `NSScrubberDelegate` has a `- didFinishInteractingWithScrubber:` method which I implemented.  However, soon after I stop manipulating the scrubber directly -- lifts the finger off the touchbar -- I get a callback, but the scroll continues to happen due to inertia.  The final item that gets selected is NOT the one when this delegate method was called back.

### Try 2

Digging further, I came across `NSAnimation`.  Though it isn't documented clearly, I gather that scrubber is also a `NSAnimatablePropertyContainer`, as its `selectedIndex` property documentation says one can animate the selection through the animator proxy thus: `scrubber.animator.selectedIndex = i`.  By that virtue, *assuming* that the animated property for the smooth panning is the `boundsOrigin`, I tried querying it.

I was able to get a `CAAnimation` by doing this

```
CAAnimation* a = [NSScrubber defaultAnimationForKey:@"boundsOrigin"];
// returns the same pointer value as above
// a = [myScrubber animationForKey:@"boundsOrigin"];
a.delegate = self;

...

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim
                finished:(BOOL)flag {
    if (flag == YES)
        NSLog(@"Animation ended!\n");
}
```

I get a valid pointer value for `a`.  However, **I get numerous calls to `animationDidStop` with all of them having `flag = YES`; as the scrubber scrolls I keep getting these calls and when the scroll stops the calls stop.  This feels closest to what I want but I dunno why so many calls come instead of just one when the animation ends.**

Since `NSScrubber`'s `NSView` or `NSScrollView` aren't exposed, I'm not sure if I'm querying the right object to get to the right `NSAnimation`.

### Try 3

I also tried the hacky route of doing this on manipulation end code in vain

```
-(void)didFinishInteractingWithScrubber:(NSScrubber *)scrubber {
    NSLog(@"Manipulation ended\n");
    NSAnimationContext*c = NSAnimationContext.currentContext;
    [c setCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Inertial scrolling stopped!\n");
    }];
}
```

The completion handler is called almost immediately, *before* the inertial scroll stops :(

### Ask

Is there anyway to know when the scrubber's pan gesture inertial animation ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to register a callback for the pan gesture's inertial scroll animation end.

Like any other scroll view, this also has the [NSScrollViewDidEndLiveScrollNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrollviewdidendlivescrollnotification). Use the notification centre to register for the callback!

```
NSScrollView *sv = myScrubber.enclosingScrollView;
// register for NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification if start is also needed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSScrollViewDidEndLiveScrollNotification
                                                  object:sv
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
                                                  NSLog(@"Scroll complete");
                                              }];
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405659/183120) for showing this approach.